# Scheduling a shell script in cron doesnot produces required output

Tags: linux, shell, cron, scheduling

I have a shell script that I have scheduled using cron using a command:

```
0 10 * * * /directory/Script.sh > /directory/log/output.log
```

The script is scheduled to run at 10 AM everyday. The script executes but produces output files only with headers, no content is there.

The script produces two output files. When I run the script manually it works fine. But when scheduled it is not producing the correct output.

Help me out.

Thanks

Comment: You mean the log file or the files which your `Script.sh` is supposed to create?

Comment: No the log file is created. But the two other output files `file1` and `file2` are also produced but they contains only headers not the content.

Comment: The script produces two output files file1 and file2

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your `Script.sh` which produces these files. Does it depend on any other parameters which produce the file?

Comment: when I am checking the `/directory/log/output.log` it tells that script has been executed but the two output files does not have the required content.

Comment: The script works fine when executed manually

Comment: few lines of script has been updated in question

Comment: That could happen because the values f, fmt and id are not in the scope. Make sure you are using absolute paths everywhere while submitting a job to cron.

Comment: Do you want me to upload all the lines in the question.

Comment: This could be relevant to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992841/cron-job-works-when-run-manually-but-not-from-crontab

Comment: entire script has been added to question

Comment: what is this absolute path ? where I have to add this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple reasons

1> Check full path of all executable in the script.

2> Ensure all environment variables are set accordingly

3> Check the script when run from the same user as the cron is executing.

Technically there is no difference between manually running a script and scheduling from cron

Comment: But when I run manually the files are produced correctly.. Is it required so ?

Comment: Can you help me with this ? How to give the absolute path ? Please

Comment: `10 05 * * * /directory/Script.sh > /directory/log/output.log 2>&1`  gives `/EC2InstanceAuditScript.sh: line 20: ec2-describe-instances: command not found`

Comment: Looks like aws cli tools are not there. Can you do `pip install awscli` and if pip is not there  `python get-pip.py` on the server

Comment: aws cli tools are there. But when scheduled on cron, it is unable to find that. I have even specified the path in the `crontab-e`  but nothing is really working. Kindly help

Comment: When you manually run the script, you run as `root` or any other user. Are the cron jobs scheduled for the same user as ec2 cli tools are available?

Comment: I run the script as root. It is the path issue. How can I add path to the cron. I tried adding path at the beginning before `0 10 * * * /EC2Script/EC2InstanceAuditScript.sh > /InstanceAuditReports/log/output.log` but nothing is working

Comment: Can you post the the log file? Without posting specific details, people on Stack Overflow would not be able to help much. 
My guess based on your previous comments is that you have not placed absolute path of `ec2-describe-instances` in your shell script. Try changing shell script to have full path of the `ec2-describe-instances`. Usually it will be `/bin/ec2-describe-instances` or you can find this by `which ec2-describe-instances` on the server

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51081/discussion-between-megha-sharma-and-anoop)